# Regex to extract part of the string

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string

```
> ma1.andl_4_1000x20x20_k1=1,k2=2,k3=1.csv.
```

I need to extract the section `k1=1,k2=2,k3=1`. I used `substr()` in R to extract.

```
substr(str, 23, nchar(str) - 4)
```

However I'm looking for a regular expression to extract the values.

Comment: So, is it just this one string and you're looking for an exact thing?  Can't you simply target the exact thing you're looking for if you're looking for something exact (which is not clear from the question)?  For example, why doesn't `gsub(".+(k1=1,k2=2,k3=1).+", "\\1", txt, perl = TRUE)` suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to extract the substr of `k1=1,k2=2,k3=1` as Jota points out, and if it is so specific a string then his solution is what you want.

For a generalized solution that'll capture `kx=y,ka=b,kj=k` you'll need to [Capture a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), your group to me being `kx=y,` where `x` is any number, `y` is any number and `,`. I left out the dot `.` for simplicity.

**REGEX**

```
((?:k\d{1,}=\d{1,}(?:,|\.)?)+)
```

**BREAKDOWN**

`(` - opening capturing bracket

`(?:` - opening non-capturing bracket, this will be repeated to capture the entire pattern

`k\d{1,}=\d{1,}` - the guts, allowing `kx=y`

`(?:,|\.)` - match the comma and last dot to allow to match the entire pattern of `kx=y(?:,|.)`

`)+` - close non-capturing bracket, repeating this pattern to capture the whole group

`)` - close capturing bracket

...and you're done. The regex will work, but I don't use `R` at all so can't test.

Read the link, the whole site is quite informative for regex

Comment: @Jota I tested with regex buddy, but not in `R`, and I didn't know you had to escape metacharacters in `R`

Comment: Thank you @gwillie for the detailed explanation. It is really helpful. And yes the numbers do change.